# is there a general solution to PDE's of the type $p(\partial_x, \partial_y)[u] = q(x,y)$ where $q,p\in \Bbb R[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

To clarify notation:

when I write $\partial_x^nu$ I mean $\frac{\partial^n}{{\partial}x^n}u$, also, I assume solutions to the type of e.q. above are always "nice enough" so that partial derivatives commute $u_{xy}=u_{yx}$.

So for e.g. if we take $p=y^3-y+x \;, \; q=x^2y+xy^2+1$ we get the PDE:

$$(\partial_y^3-\partial_y+\partial_x)[u] = u_{yyy}-u_{y}+u_{x}=x^2y+xy^2+1$$

*** A solution I have found for this particular PDE is:

$$u = x-x^2-\frac{x^2y^2}{2}-\frac{2xy^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{6}-2xy-3y^2-y+C$$

I have been toying around with PDE's of this form for a while. I haven't formally studied them, but from what I have heard they are very hard to solve. I was curious whether there is a general way to solve PDE's of the type mentioned above? Mabey even a general solution to PDE's of the type

$$p(\partial_{x_1},...,\partial_{x_n})[u]=q(x_1,...,x_n)$$
for $p,q\in \Bbb R[x_1,...,x_n]$

Perhaps a way to find polynomial solutions?

Also, I should add, If we cannot find a general solution for this type of PDE, Is there a general way to find nontrivial solutions of these PDE'S?

Comment: So $u_x+u_y = 0$ has general solution $u(x,y) = F(y-x)$, where $F$ is any function.  In general, we expect the set of solutions for a PDE to be infinite-dimensional, like this, and not merely one-dimensional as shown with a "$+C$" in it.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Secondly, I edited the question, perhaps there is a general way to find non-trivial solutions to these types of PDE's? not all solutions ofc, but a general way to find a few?